# Cannot run the OKTA sample React-OIDC app, cloned from OKta's Github repo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, okta, openid-connect

Cannot get the login page (username and password) in the  Okta sample app described in the [blog](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/30/react-okta-sign-in-widget) with the code repository at [click](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/okta-hosted-login)

Followed the OKta blog on creating OIDC CLient and using it in React app.
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/30/react-okta-sign-in-widget

Cloned the Git repo
https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/okta-hosted-login

Created the dev account on Okta and created the OIDC client and got the auth URL, CLinet ID, Client secret, etc.

npm installed the react app.

Launche dint he browser on `http://localhost:3000` 
App launches and displays the page but no login widget or page displays

Using Windows 10, node.js (10.15.3) , npm 6.4.1, Chrome browser

I removed the node_modules and package-lock.json and ran npm install again as recommended but it did not help.

```
import React from 'react';
import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget';

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.widget = new OktaSignIn(
        {
            baseUrl: 'https://dev-315128.oktapreview.com',
            clientId: '0oah3nicwuWOMY4ie356',
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
            authParams: {
            responseType: 'id_token'
        }
    }
    );
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.widget.session.get((response) => {
      if(response.status !== 'INACTIVE'){
        this.setState({user:response.login});
      }else{
        this.showLogin();
      }
    });
  }

   showLogin(){
    Backbone.history.stop();
    this.widget.renderEl({el:this.loginContainer},
      (response) => {
        this.setState({user: response.claims.email});
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  logout(){
    this.widget.signOut(() => {
      this.setState({user: null});
      this.showLogin();
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.user ? (
          <div className="container">
            <div>Welcome, {this.state.user}!</div>
            <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {this.state.user ? null : (
          <div ref={(div) => {this.loginContainer = div; }} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The browser should display the login page but I get only the Valilla page with no sign in options to Okta

Comment: Do you see any sort of error in your browser’s developer console?

Comment: No there is no error. it displays everything else just not the login widget.

Comment: I can probably help. Are you wanting to use the hosted login page? or the JS widget?